# Sed commdand - find and replace string pattern is not working when string occurs multiple times

Tags: xml, bash, sed

I am not an expert in UNIX commands but trying to create one complex replacement by finding and replacing for XML files under a directory.

Here is my file structure :

```
<LocaleCountry>
<link href="../Countries/AZ.xml" path="/Config/Countries/AZ"/>
<link href="../Countries/AM.xml" path="/Config/Countries/AM"/>
</LocaleCountry>
```

What I am trying to do make the replacement on two patterns, by usage of [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) command, sed is necessary as our server only has sed as a proper command ...

Transforming

```
from <link href="../Countries/ to <Country file="
from path="/Config/Countries/ to code="
```

So in the end my output should look like :

```
<LocaleCountry>
<Country file="AZ.xml" code="AZ"/>
<Country file="AM.xml" code="AM"/>
</LocaleCountry>
```

What I have tried works, but not multiple "link" elements, it only changes the first one and won't touch the others, most probably I couldn't create a correct expression for my pattern ...

Here is what I have tried:

```
sed -i 's#<link href="../Countries/#<Country file="#' *.xml
sed -i 's#path="/Config/Countries/#code="#' *.xml
```

Can you please check what I'm doing wrong and suggest a solution if possible?

Comment: It was not working... when "link" string occurs more than ones it would only changed the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tell the substitution command to make it global:

```
sed -i 's#<link href="../Countries/#<Country file="#g' *.xml
sed -i 's#path="/Config/Countries/#code="#g' *.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for quite, fast support!